# Скрипт по powershall

Tags: powershell

Мне нужно найти процесс который запущен меньше минуты и вывести информацию о нем (ID процесса, его имя, время работы).

Так как я новечек в изучении, не могу понять какой именно командой воспользоваться. Примерно блок схему в голове я представляю. Нужно от текущего времени вычесть время процесса и сравнить с помощью if с минутой.

Comment: посмотрите команду Get-Process, а я могу помочь поулчить дату старта процесса, а дальше попробуйте сами сравнивать и решить задачу. в Итоге как решите, опубликуйте тут ответ. хорошо?  `(Get-Date (Get-Process explorer).StartTime).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`

Comment: У меня получился такой скрипт, но не могу докончить. выдает ошибку


Foreach ($proc in Get-Process)
{
if ($proc.starttime)
{
$t = ((New-TimeSpan -start($proc.StartTime).tostring("g")) | select -Expand TotalSecond)
if ($t -lt 60)
{
Write-Output $proc
}
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так вывести:

```
$processes = (Get-Process)
ForEach ($process in $processes) 
{
    $name = $process.Name
    $time = $process.StartTime

    if($time) {
        $seconds = [System.Math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start ($time)).TotalSeconds)
        if($seconds -le 60) {
            echo "$name, $seconds"
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось.